# What is the best way to create a function that runs multiple functions

Tags: r

In R I am attempting to create a function that will do multiple other functions with just one command input.

I have tried

```
data_answer<-function(){
data<-read.csv("data.csv",stringsAsFactors=TRUE)
summary(data)
Cor(data[c("x","y","z","h")])
pairs(data[c("x","y","z","h")])
data_train<-data[1,1000]
data_test<-data[1001,1500]
data_model<-lm(h~x+y+z,data=data)
data_pred<-predict(data_model,data_test)
}
```

All that results is a big multiple scatterplot window.
So my question is: 
How do I write a function that runs all the above commands and shows the results of each and use a outside data set as the parameter. So then I can just enter `data_answer("_____")` in R and it will run all the functions on that dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make your function a function of file name:

```
data_answer<-function(filename){
  data<-read.csv(filename,stringsAsFactors=TRUE)
```

then either `print` all the functions you call on the data that otherwise return data, or return a list of all the results. For example:

```
f = function(x){
  print(mean(x))
  print(sd(x))
}

f(runif(100))
```

will print the mean and sd of 100 random numbers, and:

```
f2 = function(x){
  result = list(mean=mean(x), sd=sd(x))
  return(result)
}

f2(runif(100))
```

will return a list of the mean and sd which will then get printed. You can store it and print it later, or access the values:

```
zz = f2(runif(100))
zz
zz$mean
```